# Finding an element in map by its value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm creating a `HandleManager` whose purpose is to simply map `Handle`s (which is a `typedef` of `long long int`) to `string`s. The purpose is so that objects that use a `Handle` can also be identified via `string`s if it helps a user remember the object. In which case, in this map:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<Handle, std::string> HandleMap;
```

both types in the pair are keys insofar they can be used to identify anything. So far everything has compiled apart from the code which needs to get the `Handle`. The purpose is such that when a user allocates a `string` like so:

```
handle("myHandle");
```

A `Handle` is generated randomly and then the `string` passed is paired with it in the foresaid map. What I want now is to be able to get the `Handle` that is paired with the `string` based on the `string` that is passed:

```
Handle HandleManager::id(const std::string &name)
{
    HandleMap::iterator it = pHandles.find(name);

    if (it != pHandles.end())
        return it->first;
    return -1;
}
```

But for some weird reason the compiler complains about this:

```
HandleManager.cpp:48:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<long long int, std::basic_string<char> >::find(const string&)’
```

In the foresaid map, the `string` is the value and the `Handle` is the key. So how can I get the **key** from the `unordered_map` based on the *value* contained therein?

Comment: Maybe you need [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Alas, you'll have to write such a function yourself.

Comment: You can't with a `std::unordered_map`, the only way is to iterate over all entries. IIRC boost provides a type, that allows to lookup by value also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the member function `find` to search for key only. To search for a value, you can use a `std::find_if` with a lambda function (if you use C++11), or to traverse the map (ok in previous C++ version):

```
for (HandleMap::const_iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
  if (it->second == name) return it->first;
} 
// or value not found
```

On the other hand, if searching for a value is a very common operation, you may want to have two maps: `std::unordered_map<Handle, std::string>` and `std::unordered_map<std::string, Handle>`. In that case, you have to make sure you perform insertions, deletions, etc. in both maps to keep then synchronized.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: But attention must be observed as the key values must ensure that there are no collisions by inverting the values in the map

Answer (score 13):

`std::unordered_map::find` operates on the key, not the value. You can use `std::find_if`:

```
Handle HandleManager::id(const std::string &name)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(pHandles), std::end(pHandles),
                           [&name](auto&& p) { return p.second == name; });

    if (it == std::end(pHandles))
        return -1;
 
    return it->first;
}
```

Note that `auto`, `std::begin`, `std::end` and lambdas are C++11 and generic lambdas are C++14, so substitute those out if you're stuck with an old compiler.

Comment: You forgot to capture `name`.

And `p` is a pair.

So it should be:

    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(pHandles), std::end(pHandles),
        [& name](auto && pair) { return pair.second == name; });

Answer (score 3):

> But for some weird reason the compiler complains about this:

Of course it does, the `find` function is for lookup up by key and you're not doing that.

To find a value you need to visit every element until you find it (or use a bidirectional map which maps values back to keys, e.g. [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer from @TartanLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780139/1180868) (*):

```
Handle HandleManager::id(const std::string & name) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(std::begin(pHandles), std::end(pHandles),
            [& name](auto && pair) {
        return pair.second == name;
    });
    if (it == std::end(pHandles)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return it->first;
}
```

*(*): Because it doesn't seem possible to format code in comments.*