# Get enum key from unordered map by string value

Tags: c++, algorithm, enums, key, unordered-map

I need a function that needs to check if the input (`std::string`) is unique and return its corresponding enum value.

I already have been able to implement this function with just a simple vector, which checks if the input is unique.

it should return `enumE::HELLO`.

I tried to adapt the code above for the vector to suit this function, but I am not really getting anywhere.

Comment: What should it return in the not found / not unique case? What exactly have you tried so far and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a map backwards. If you want to use a map to look for something, that should be the map's key, and not the value.

Comment: @Artyer In the enumE class, there is value NOTFOUND AND NOTUNIQUE. I've tried to use a for loop but then I get an error message "no viable conversion"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the reason I do this is because I want to use the key as a switch case value, which is not possible with a string.

Comment: Well, you can run a loop over the map just as well as you can over a vector. Something like `for (auto& [enumValue, command] : commands) { ... }` . Or, if your compiler is not sufficiently recent to support structured bindings, then `for (auto& elem : commands) { auto enumValue = elem.first; auto command = elem.second; ...}`

Comment: Check this previous question on using find_if: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780046/finding-an-element-in-map-by-its-value

Comment: What does the question of what's the key versus what's a value in a map has anything  to do, whatsoever, with using one or another in some `switch` case value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my mistake, I thought key values of a map should be ideally ints.

Comment: Map keys can be any data type that implements strict weak ordering. You can even implement your own class, define your own `operator<` that implements strict weak ordering, and use your class as a map key. And, again, what key or value a map has bears no relationship to some `switch` statement, somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of your example, [here is a quick implementation](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LWqqUly7KEV91j2y). Of course, the logic may not be entirely what you wrote, but I am sure you can tweak it.

- Why would you iterate through the whole string if `std::string` has a `std::string::find` function which will find a substring for you?
- Is it necessary to go through all the trouble you wrote above? Does the code need to be that dense and unreadable?

Feel free to play around with that function and implement your logic.

Comment: Thank you. I fear that the code needs to be that dense to make it return a unique value, but I'll manage that problem myself!